# One to one Mapping on composite key referenced by column which is not present in Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm new to JPA. I couldn't find a solution to my problem yet. I'm using spring boot. I have 2 entities *Person and PersonDetail*. Both have one to one relationship. And has composite primary key in both. My entities as follows.

**Person.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonId id;
    
    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    private Date createdOn;
    
//  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//  @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "person_code", referencedColumnName = "PERSON_CODE"),
//          @JoinColumn(name = "reg_code", referencedColumnName = "REG_CODE"),
//          @JoinColumn(name = "lan_code", referencedColumnName = "LAN_CODE")})
//  private PersonDetail personDetail;
}
```

**PersonId.java**

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class PersonId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name = "PERSON_CODE")
    private String personCode;
    
    @Column(name = "REG_CODE")
    private String regCode;
}
```

**PersonDetail.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonDetail")
public class PersonDetail {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonDetailId id;
    
    @Column(name = "REMARKS")
    private String remarks;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "person_code", referencedColumnName = "PERSON_CODE"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "reg_code", referencedColumnName = "REG_CODE") })
    private Person person;
}
```

**PersonDetailId.java**

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class PersonDetailId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name = "PERSON_CODE")
    private String personCode;
    
    @Column(name = "REG_CODE")
    private String regCode;
    
    @Column(name = "LAN_CODE")
    private String lanCode;
}
```

As you see lanCode is not present in Person.java. With PersonDetail repository I'm able to get list of person details along with Person data.

But what if I want to get person list/object and get corresponding person detail. Since it's one to one mapping I can get by PersonDetail but wanted to know how to map the other way.

In Person class I had added mapping (lines commented). But when I try to fetch data I get exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
.
.
.
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=PERSON0_.LAN_CODE, DRIVER=4.31.10
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:810)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:140)
```

If I remove LAN_CODE mapping from Person class, I get below error on startup.

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(PERSON_CODE, REG_CODE) of com.ss.model.Person.personDetail referencing com.ss.model.PersonDetail not mapped to a single property
```

How to map it properly? Is it possible?

Comment: How would you join `PersonDetail` to `Person` in a plain SQL query?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer based on REG_CODE and PERSON_CODE. That's what I tried initially. But it got me the error I added in last.

Comment: Then simply remove the `@EmbeddedId`, move the properties of `PersonDetailId` out into `PersonDetail` and annotate the fields with `@Id`. Then it should work. There has been no need for `@Embeddable` for quite some time

Comment: This set of keys to uniquely identify person and personDetail don't make sense - Did someone intend Person to have a 1:M to PersonDetail? If so, use a OneToMany with a 'mappedby= person' designation to have it use the existing foreign keys. Otherwise, if this can really be a OneToOne, PersonDetail should just use the PERSON_CODE and REG_CODE as its unique identifier.

Comment: @Chris unfortunately this is the DB design and it's legacy we can't change. Only code is getting migrated.

Comment: If this is a 1:1, then yes, you do have the power to change. The ID in JPA does NOT need to match the primary keys in the database. The only restrictions are that what is marked as the ID uniquely identifies the entity, and can be used for foreign keys. There is no reason to use LAN_CODE as the ID if PersonDetail is unique using the PERSON_CODE and REG_CODE data. But doesn't matter - just use a bidirectional 1:1 - again, just use 'mappedby="person"' in the Person->PersonDetail mapping